# How can i return the scores in RadioButton? (making a test)

Tags: android, oop, radio-button

i am making a MC test. i want to count the scores for correct ans.
this is my code. i want to return the scores in onRadioButtonClicked() how can i do that?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general_test, container, false);

    handInBtn=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.handInBtn);       
    handInBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), scores+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }});

    return rootView;
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.Radio1a:
            if (checked)
                scores++;
        case R.id.Radio2a:
            if (checked)
                scores++;
    }
}
```

Comment: in android you can create a radio group and there is redio group listener so you get seleted radio button and get value of that button and compare with correct answer if correct then increment else leave.

Comment: you want to toast the score value after every check/uncheck?!

Answer (score 0):

in android you can create a radio group and there is redio group listener so you get seleted radio button and get value of that button and compare with correct answer if correct then increment else leave.

```
for Example.
RadioGroup
    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
       Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

            if (checkedId.gettext() == "Correct answer") {
                //some code
   correct++

            } else  {
                //some code
            }

        }

    });
```